# What does bijection mean with regards to Combinatorics and Sets?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I think I understand the 2 conditions that are necessary for a function to be bijective, but in a book of Combinatorics I am reading it talks about Bijections with sets and with combinatorial problems, and doesn't explain what it is very well in my opinion. It simply says it's a one-to-one correspondence between different items... What does a bijection mean then with regards to Combinatorics and sets?

For example, earlier in the book it gave this problem:

> Suppose that $a,~b,~c,~d$ and $e$ are positive integers. How many solutions are there to the equation $$a+b+c+d+e=11$$?

This can be found by considering $11$ items and $4$ gaps between different items out of the $10$ possible gaps, so the solution is $\binom{10}{4}$. I understand this perfectly.

Later, when talking briefly about bijections it says of the aforementioned problem that the coding (of $4$ objects that can be chosen of one and $6$ of the same type of object that can't be chosen (in this case, gaps)) is 'unique and reversible, or, in other words, that it represented a bijection.'

What does it mean by this? What bijection is it talking about? I have no idea. Also, I don't understand what it means by reversible.

Thank you for your help in this very basic question.

Comment: It seems to me that it’s pretty clear. If you have two sets of things, say $A$ and $B$, a bijection between them is simply a one-to-one correspondence between the things in $A$ and the things in $B$, i.e., a function $f:A\to B$ or a function $f:B\to A$ that is both $1$-$1$ (injective) and onto (surjective). It’s no different in combinatorics from what it is in any other context. Can you be more explicit about just what’s puzzling you?

Comment: The idea is that if you want to prove that $a = b$, one way to do it is to find sets $A$ and $B$ so that $|A| = a$ and $|B| = b$ ($|S|$ meaning the number of elements of a set $S$) and then prove that $|A| = |B|$.  And one way to prove $|A| = |B|$ is to find a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott please see my edited question.

Comment: @JairTaylor also please see my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me see if I can show you in detail what’s going on behind the scenes, so to speak, in that problem and the book’s explanation.

Let

$$S=\{\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\rangle\in\Bbb Z^+:x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=11\}\,;$$

we want to know $|S|$. The idea behind the solution is to find a set $A$ whose cardinality is easier to determine and show that $|A|=|S|$ by showing that there is a bijection between $A$ and $S$.

In this case we imagine lining up $11$ items: $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5,c_6,c_7,c_8,c_9,c_{10},c_{11}$. We let $G$ be the set of gaps between adjacent items; clearly $|G|=10$. Finally, we let $A=\{X\subseteq G:|X|=4\}$, the set of $4$-element subsets of $G$; we know that $|A|=\binom{10}4$. If we can find a bijection between $A$ and $S$, we’ll have shown that $|S|=\binom{10}4$.

And you already know what the bijection is: if $s=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\rangle\in S$, we let $f(s)=\{g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4\}\in A$, where $g_1$ is the gap between $c_{x_1}$ and $c_{x_1+1}$, $g_2$ is the gap between $c_{x_1+x_2}$ and $c_{x_1+x_2+1}$, $g_3$ is the gap between $c_{x_1+x_2+x_3}$ and $c_{x_1+x_2+x_3+1}$, and $g_4$ is the gap between $c_{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}$ and $c_{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+1}$, so that there are $x_1$ items before the gap $g_1$, $x_2$ items between gaps $g_1$ and $g_2$, $x_3$ items between gaps $g_2$ and $g_3$, $x_4$ items between $g_3$ and $g_4$, and $x_5$ items after gap $g_4$. Clearly this set of gaps is completely determined by the solution $s$: given $s$, there is a unique set of $4$ gaps described in this way by $s$. This simply means that $f$ is a function from $S$ to $A$ and is what the book’s *unique* is getting at.

*Reversible* simply means that the function $f$ has an inverse, i.e., that it is a bijection: it is a surjection, because every set of $4$ gaps is $f(s)$ for some solution $s\in S$, and it is an injection, because if we are given a set of $X=\{g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4\}$ of $4$ gaps, we can determine the unique $s\in S$ such that $f(s)=X$.

Comment: I think I understand it better now, thank you :) I will read over your answer a few more times to ensure I understand it fully.

Comment: @A-levelStudent: You’re welcome. Feel free to ask if something isn’t clear.

Comment: What do you mean by $c_{x_1+1}$? Do you mean the $c$ term after $c_{x_1}$?

Comment: @A-levelStudent: Yes. For instance, if $x_1=3$, then $c_{x_1+1}=c_{3+1}=c_4$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll continue re-reading it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $s$? A particular choice of the different $x_i$ values?

Comment: @A-levelStudent: Yes; that’s exactly what $s=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\rangle\in S$ says.

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer, I believe I understand it fully now. Sorry about my last question; I haven't ever studied sets or set notation in detail before as I am currently in high school and sets aren't in the Maths or Further Maths syllabuses that I study, so I wasn't totally sure about it.

Comment: @A-levelStudent: That’s okay. May I ask what combinatorics book you’re reading?

Comment: I am reading Introduction to Combinatorics: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Combinatorics-Leversha-Gerry/dp/1906001243/

Comment: @A-levelStudent: Ah, that one I don’t know, so I can’t really offer any useful comments or suggestions. (Not surprising, since I’m in the U.S.)

Comment: I thought that might be the case, no worries. It's really excellent, but the only problem is that very occasionally the explanations are somewhat brief; for me anyway :)

Comment: Just to doublecheck my understanding of bijections, eg with partitions: If you peform an operation on a particular partition to obtain a different partition, if that operation is reversible then the 2 types of partitions form a bijection and there are an equal number of each type of partition?

Comment: @A-levelStudent: Yes, that’s right: it’s a bijection between the set of partitions to which it can be applied and the set of partitions that it produces.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I don't mean to take advantage of you, but would you mind looking at another question of mine? I'm still unclear about the answer to my question in the link.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847697/prove-that-binomn0-binomn2-binomn4-binomn1-binomn3/3847710?noredirect=1#comment7937261_3847710

Comment: @A-levelStudent: I’ve written up a somewhat different approach to the problem; **Robby the Belgian**’s approach works fine, but you may find that having more than one available helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is like speed-dating.

If $10$ women want to date $10$ men simultaneously, you have to match every woman with a man, every man with a woman, such that every man has a woman to date and every woman has a man to date.

To each element of the first set (the women) is associated one and only one element of the second set (the men), and reciprocally.